# Upload progress using HttpClient in Blazor Wasm

Tags: c#, .net, dotnet-httpclient, blazor, blazor-client-side

I'm trying to get file upload progress inside a blazor web assembly app.

```
var handler = new ProgressMessageHandler();
handler.InnerHandler = new WebAssemblyHttpMessageHandler();
handler.HttpSendProgress += (object sender, HttpProgressEventArgs e) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("bytes transfered= " + e.BytesTransferred.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine("total bytes= " + e.TotalBytes.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine("progress percentage= " + e.ProgressPercentage.ToString());
};

var http = new HttpClient(handler);
http.BaseAddress = new Uri(NavigationManager.BaseUri);
await http.PostJsonAsync("api/...", attachedFile);

Console.WriteLine("Done");
```

I came up with the following code, but when I upload a file I get a single event instantly reporting 100% completion even if the post request last a few seconds.

```
WASM: bytes transfered= 277983
blazor.webassembly.js:1 WASM: total bytes= 277983
blazor.webassembly.js:1 WASM: progress percentage= 100
```

There is a few questions on SO dealing with upload progress but I want to use the Http.ProgressMessageHandler if possible

Comment: Did you try with a bigger file ?

Comment: Have you seen this: https://blog.stevensanderson.com/2019/09/13/blazor-inputfile/

Comment: @aguafrommars yes, and with the chrome developper tools option that allow you to limit the upload/download speed.

Comment: @Flores I'm actually using steve's component but
there is only one example using memory stream, not http client request. Maybe it's possible to make a post request using a stream, I'll look at that

Comment: Actualy it's not possible using client-side HttpClient because it use a browser [fetch request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) by js interrop. The fetch request API doen't support stream at the moment. https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/release/3.0/src/Components/Web.JS/src/Services/Http.ts

Comment: You should consider writing you own service using a js interopt for XHR