# File Upload and save in Blazor Server Side

Tags: file, blazor, blazor-server-side

How upload and save file in Database Using `HttpPostedFileBase` in Blazor

```cs
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase postedFile)
    {
        byte[] bytes;
        using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(postedFile.InputStream))
        {
            bytes = br.ReadBytes(postedFile.ContentLength);
        }
        FilesEntities entities = new FilesEntities();
        entities.tblFiles.Add(new tblFile
        {
            Name = Path.GetFileName(postedFile.FileName),
            ContentType = postedFile.ContentType,
            Data = bytes
        });
        entities.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Comment: And what's the issue ?

Comment: I cant able to use HttpPostedFileBase in C# code and cant pass the value too

Comment: I should use IFormFile instead https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-3.0

Comment: Ok, how send the value to controller

Comment: Is that help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58095977/upload-progress-using-httpclient-in-blazor-wasm#comment102603079_58095977 ?